# Define $f:\mathbb{Z}/4\mathbb{Z}\to \mathbb{Z}/4\mathbb{Z}$ by $f([a])=[3a+1]$.

Tags: functions, proof-writing

> Define $f:\mathbb{Z}/4\mathbb{Z}\to \mathbb{Z}/4\mathbb{Z}$ by $f([a])=[3a+1]$. Prove that $f$ is well-defined, surjective and injective

I don't really have a problem with figuring out if it's well-defined, surjective or injective, but I do have a problem understanding the $f([a]) = [3a+1]$. like do I say $b = 3a+1$, and then... I'm not sure?

Comment: I think the brackets denote the quotient element. So that $f([1])=[4]=[0]$

Answer (score 1):

The elements of $\mathbb{Z}/4\mathbb{Z}$ are all of the form $[a]$, where $a\in\mathbb{Z}$. However, $[a]$ can also be represented as $[b]$, with $a\ne b$; for instance,
$$
[0]=[4]=[8]=\dots
$$

Defining $f([a])=[3a+1]$ requires showing that, if $[a]=[b]$, then $[3a+1]=[3b+1]$, so the image of $[a]$ doesn't depend on the particular element we use to represent it. To continue the example, you would define $f([0])=[3\cdot0+1]$, but it somebody else used $4$ and computed $f([0])=f([4])=[3\cdot4+1]$, we'd be in great difficulties if $[1]\ne[13]$.

However, in this case they are equal. Is this true for all elements in $\mathbb{Z}/4\mathbb{Z}$?

Suppose $[a]=[b]$; this means $a\equiv b \pmod{4}$, which implies $3a\equiv3b\pmod{4}$ and so $3a+1\equiv3b+1\pmod{4}$, or $[3a+1]=[3b+1]$. OK, $f$ is well defined.